# C# How to find substring in string?

Tags: get, serial-port, substring, indexof, text-extraction

I have this data:

AC level : FAIL
ADC AC - 0x0440
AC level : FAIL
Average ADC Batt - 0x733e

I want to get the Adc Ac value for example the 0x0440 but when I want to store it in the database ,the output will display ****0**x737eBatt Level : MidADC****** but it happened intermittently.

Here is my code:

```
     public static string getBetween(string strSource, string strStart, string strEnd)
       {
        if (strSource.Contains(strStart) && strSource.Contains(strEnd))
        {
            int Start, End;
            Start = strSource.IndexOf(strStart, 1) + strStart.Length;
            End = strSource.IndexOf(strEnd, Start);
            return strSource.Substring(Start, End - Start);
        }

        return "";
    }
   // Find ADC value
       string ADC = getBetween(serialdata, "-", "AC");
```

Answer (score 0):

You should probably try to extract the values by their key, rather than relying on characters before and after. In your example the string "AC" already appears twice before the text that you are interested in. Try a function like the following, to get any value:

```
static bool TryGetValue(string serialData, string key, out string value)
{
    var m = Regex.Match(serialData, $".*{Regex.Escape(key)}\\s*[-:](?<value>.*)$", RegexOptions.Multiline);
    value = m.Groups["value"].Value.Trim();
    return m.Success;
}
```

you'd call it like this:

```
if (TryGetValue(serialData, "ADC AC", out var value))
{
    Console.WriteLine(value);
}
```